# SQL database Mail Password change permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2, dbmail

SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008 R2

I have to make use of email accounts with Database Mail whose passwords have a life of 90 days so therefore have to ensure that smtp Authentication passwords are updated in a timely fashion.

I currently have a new member of staff for whom I do not wish to grant System Admin (SA) privileges to. However I would like them to be able to update DB Mail passwords in my absence which I understand do require SQL SA rights.

Does anyone know anyway around this and how I can grant/configure  this specific privilege?

Comment: When you say "email accounts", are you talking about the user (and password) for authenticating to an SMTP server?

Comment: Yes precisely, and the 90 day password life is fixed and can't be change.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today:  [updating a Database mail account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188381(v=sql.105).aspx) requires  membership in the sysadmin fixed server role.  What about a single db mail account that authenticates to the SMTP server with a custom Active Directory account that is configured with a password that never expires?  Would that work for you?

Comment: Not an option I am afraid for certain processes I have to email data via government controlled Mail server via a secure link. Government set and dictate 90 days expiry on smtp authentication passwords

Comment: What about the login account that is used for SQL Agent?  Does that have memebership in SYSADMIN?  Maybe you come up with some customized code to update the passwords (as needed) and have it run as a SQL Job.  Just a thought...